# can't save data with image in hosting, but can save in localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-hosting

I made a form with php, one of content of the form is a upload image function.

When I'm running the form in localhost, the data is successfully stored in my database, but when I try through my host, the form can't store data in database.

Source Controller :

```
    $this->load->library('upload');
    $nmfile = "file_".time(); //nama file saya beri nama langsung dan diikuti fungsi time
    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/'; //path folder
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp'; //type yang dapat diakses bisa anda sesuaikan
    $config['max_size'] = '3072'; //maksimum besar file 3M
    $config['max_width']  = '5000'; //lebar maksimum 5000 px
    $config['max_height']  = '5000'; //tinggi maksimu 5000 px
    $config['file_name'] = $nmfile; //nama yang terupload nantinya

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if($_FILES['filefoto']['name'])
    {
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('filefoto'))
        {
            $gbr = $this->upload->data();
            $data = array(
            'nm_gbr' =>$gbr['file_name']                
            );

            $res = $this->M_tambahdata->tambahdata("anggota",$data); 

            $config2['image_library'] = 'gd2'; 
            $config2['source_image'] = $this->upload->upload_path.$this->upload->file_name;
            $config2['new_image'] = './assets/hasil_resize/'; 
            $config2['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $config2['width'] = 100; //lebar setelah resize menjadi 100 px
            $config2['height'] = 100; //lebar setelah resize menjadi 100 px
            $this->load->library('image_lib',$config2); 

            if ($res>=1) {

            echo "<script>alert('Data berhasil disimpan')</script>";
            echo "<script>window.location='".base_url()."tambahdata'</script>";
            }

            else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', 'Maaf, ulangi data gagal di inputkan.');
                redirect('dashboard/index');
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Source view :

```
      <h5>Foto</h5>
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i></span>
                <input name="filefoto" type="file" class="form-control">
              </div>                                                                    
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
          </div><!-- /.box -->
```

Comment: if it working fine on local then it must be file permission issue, check your image folder permission and give that folder write permission

Comment: What is the SO from local and remote server? Seems like a permission issue. Also, on linux, `./` is to execute a command.

Answer (score 0):

Your paths are wrong I think.

This:

```
$config['upload_path'] = './assets/uploads/';
```

To:

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'assets/uploads/';
```

And this:

```
$config2['new_image'] = './assets/hasil_resize/';
```

To:

```
$config2['new_image'] = 'assets/hasil_resize/';
```